# Requests per second vs. IO per seconds (IOPS) AND concurrent users vs connections

Tags: database, concurrency

I'm pretty new to the world of databases and I was wondering - what is the difference between "Requests per second (RPS)" and "IO per second (IOps)"

From what I know 1 Request can be made up of several I/Os (which are input ouputs). Is this a correct understanding?

Also, in the context of databases, are concurrent connections the same as concurrent users? I would assume that every connection would equate to a user. Is this right?

Please feel free to correct me or throw me examples, links, resources to read up on. I'm a total newbie at this, and would absolutely love to ramp up on my database basics!